# Laravel Mix - How to watch multiple entry points for changes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I've split frontend and admin webpack.mix files like so:

webpack.mix.js:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

if (process.env.section) {
    require(`${__dirname}/webpack.mix.${process.env.section}.js`);
}
```

Then a seperare `webpack.mix.admin.js` and `webpack.mix.website.js` file for controlling the mix with the following in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env process.env.section=website NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env process.env.section=website NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env process.env.section=website NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env process.env.section=website NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "admin-dev": "npm run admin-development",
    "admin-development": "cross-env process.env.section=admin NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "admin-watch": "cross-env process.env.section=admin NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "admin-watch-poll": "npm run admin-watch -- --watch-poll",
    "admin-hot": "cross-env process.env.section=admin NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "admin-prod": "npm run admin-production",
    "admin-production": "cross-env process.env.section=admin NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
```

It's all running well but I can only run `npm run watch` on the frontend when ideally I want to watch both frontend and admin files for changes.

I've tried `npm run watch & npm run admin-watch` but the latter is ignored

At the moment I am watching the frontend files and running `npm run admin-prod` as and when required but this has started to get a little frustrating

Comment: Personally I'd use two terminal windows. The thing here is you're explicitly saying you want to control which "group" of files should be transpiled based  on the environment variable but from what I see there's no harm in transpiling both in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer, but in my configuration I'm able to run 2 scripts in parallel with [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all). Take a look to `lint` task in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "assets": "gulp assets",
    "lint:js": "eslint --max-warnings 0 app/Resources/frontend/scripts/",
    "lint:css": "stylelint app/Resources/frontend/",
    "lint": "run-p lint:css lint:js",
    "lint:fix": "run-p lint:css --fix lint:js --fix"
},
```

Hope this helps :)